# PDF browser Plugin for IE 8/9. No File association. MSI exec

Tags: pdf, windows-installer

I work in a an office of 50 desktops that are going to be replaced with thinclients.  As we are rolling out these Win 7 Embedded machines, we notice that a handful of websites require the use of a PDF browser plugin. It displayed a big red X instead.

We use Citrix for published apps, and publish out Nuance PDF8. However the staff uses IE on the local machine to save on Citrix XenApp resources. We are able to work around this problem by installing FoxIt PDF. While runnning the Installer we uncheck the box for "Associate PDF extension" Or Open PDFs with FoxIt.

By not associating PDFs with the local install of FoxIt, network PDFs still will open in Nuance PDF like it is expected to.  I am trying to tailor the MSI installer so that we can publish this out with Group Policy or an Install Script.

Goal:
Modify Installer to switch to custom setup and enable brower plug-in (view in brower) but not associate with PDFs.

I have searched on MSInstaller help sites, but I find my self even more confused.  I have Orca installed for modifying MSIs and making MS transforms.